# JSP page included in servlet not rendering satisfactorily

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two jsp files (header.jspf and footer.jspf) that I want to include in a page produced by the doGet method of a servlet (Menu.java). I'm doing this by use of the RequestDispatcher.include() method. The header.jspf file only contains html so it renders fine. The footer.jspf file, however, contains both EL and JSP tags, neither of which render on the servlet page produced by Menu.java.

Looking at the source code of the page produced by Menu.java I understand that the reason for this problem is that the EL and JSP is not evaluated prior to being included in the servlet so it is just presumed by the browser that it is html.

While I'm guessing that what I'm trying to do may be poor (and deprecated) practice, I'd just like to find out if there is a way to get an included jsp file to render in a servlet just as it would in a jsp page when it contains EL and jsp tags?

I'm thinking that this question is general enough not to require my code to be posted, however if I'm wrong please tell me so and I will update with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to have `RequestDispatcher.include()` files processed, but including the footer explicitly will very likely work:

```
<%@include file="footer.jspf" %>
```